# How to clone Nest's [String(Ignore)] attribute for my own method

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest, custom-attributes

I am trying to clone `[String(Ignore)]` attribute of Nest for my own method that saves process logs. I have already done something but it doesn't work.

Basically, what I would like to do is, I'd like to create a custom attribute that will provide me to choose if to save property to the elasticsearch or not.

So, I have a `SaveUserProcessLog` method.
Then I create a custom attribute named as `MyProcessLogDetailAttribute` and inherited from nest's `StringAttribute`:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class MyUserProcessLogDetailAttribute : StringAttribute
{
    public MyUserProcessLogDetailAttribute(bool SaveProperty)
    {
        Ignore = !SaveProperty; //when true, ignore is false
    }
}
```

And I am adding this attribute to the properties which I want to be saved in.

```
[MyUserProcessLogDetail(SaveProperty:false)]
public Guid UserCode { get; set; }

[MyUserProcessLogDetail(SaveProperty:false)]
public string FullName { get; set; }
```

Is inheriting from Nest's attribute approach right?

Why am I not using the original `[String(Ignore=false/true)]` attribute of Nest is because I may want to create a new attribute to save property for another method. For instance, don't save `UserCode` for `UserProcessLog()` method but save for `SaveUserAmendments()`.

I hope I have been clear about this.

Comment: I'm not seeing what this is buying you over simply using `[String(Ignore=true)]`? For your derived attribute, you still need to pass `true/false` so it semantically works the same as `StringAttribute`

Comment: @RussCam I do not want to store, for instance, UserCode to elastic ProcessLog type whereas I may want to save it to elastic UserLog type. If I use `[String(Ignore=true)]` Nest will always ignore it. So I need to create two different custom attribute. Or can I use this something like  `[String(Ignore=true, TypeName="UserLog")]`
`[String(Ignore=false, TypeName="ProcessLog")]`?

Comment: If you have two models with the same properties that must be mapped differently then I would use fluent mapping for them rather than attributes. Take a look at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/2.x/auto-map.html